# How to bind with struct in ReactiveCocoa with Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I will need to change the border color when meet certain condition like so, but I can't find a way to go through the compiler:

```
RAC(self.addrTextField.layer, borderColor) = [validateAddressSignal map:^ CGColorRef* (NSArray *array) {

    if (array.count) {
        return [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
    }
    return [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most elegant solution to a similar question asked on [Reactive Cocoa's GitHub Issue](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/issues/1268) tracker is the following posted by Erik Price:

```
@interface UIView (MyCategoryName)
- (void)setMyBorderColor:(UIColor *)color;
@end

@implementation UIView
- (void)setMyBorderColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    self.layer.borderColor = color.CGColor;
}
@end

// ...

RAC(myTextField, myBorderColor) = mySignalOfUIColors;
```

Basically, make it easy to bind the color by adding a category to UIView.

Comment: Side note, Stack Overflow is a great resource but the RAC contributors are very active at answering questions on GitHub - I totally recommend asking vanilla Reactive Cocoa questions there first!

Comment: great. I think posting here can help a lots people

Comment: One more thing, so it means that there is not way to bind a struct?

Comment: There is - you could bridge the struct as the OP on the GitHub issue tried, i.e.:

`return (__bridge id)[color CGColor];`

however this has potential problems with whether or not that CGColor ought to be retained, and when it needs to be released. If possible it is best to solve this at the UIKit/Objective-C level.